# VBS Script To Open Certain Applications Depending on Computer Name

Tags: vbscript

Trying to create a VBScript to open one of two different functions depending on the computer name. 
Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("WinNTSystemInfo")
strComputerName = objSysInfo.ComputerName

Sub MIS()
objShell.Run "firefox"
objShell.Run "P:\Private"
objShell.Run ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_86\pythonw.exe""")
objShell.Run ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_86\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw""")
End Sub

Sub Norm()
objShell.Run "firefox"
objShell.Run "P:\Private"
End Sub

If strComputerName = "BDREDCTR175-74" Then
MIS()
Else
Norm()
End If
```

However when I run it it gives me the error:

[image: Varialble is undefined: 'objSysInfo']

Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript undefined variable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001136/vbscript-undefined-variable-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Option Explicit` forces you to define all variables you use.

So add `Dim objSysInfo` above `Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("WinNTSystemInfo")`.